# Is it possible to reopen a menu?

Tags: matlab, menu

My question is very simple.

I need to find out if its possible to reopen a menu already created.
Like this:

```
choice = menu('Command','1','2','Quit');
```

And command 2 is opening a new menu with the fallowing:

```
choice2 = menu('Command','3','4','Return');
```

When I click on ***Return*** I want to make the ***choice*** menu pop back up.

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

A bit long for a comment, so what if you just check `choice2`, and if the result is 'return' (i.e. its value is 3) then you call the first menu again?

Eg:

```
clear
clc
close all

choice = menu('Command','1','2','Quit');

choice2 = menu('Command','3','4','Return');

if choice2 ==3
choice = menu('Command','1','2','Quit')
end
```

What you could do for more versatility is to create a simple GUI with text boxes that you would be able to call anytime and customize as you wish.

Comment: The problem here is that the code will be almost an infinite loop of if/else, cause with that code i need to define the actions on 1,2 and Quit again.

Comment: Oh then I'm a bit lost; if you always need to check the actions then you will need many if/else statements right? Can you give more context about your code? Like what do you really want to do with it? Thanks.